# PHPUnit Code Coverage and external multiprocesing

Tags: phpunit, subprocess, code-coverage

I want to create code coverage with `PHPUnit` for all my code, but almost half of my code is run as sub-processors with `React\ChildProcess\Process`

I do not know if it possible at all, but want to ask here.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look through the ReactPHP test suite to see if you can find any inspiration in that.